# Greenplum pandas dataframe integration in plpython procedure (from INSIDE the database)

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, server-side, greenplum

Is it possible to use pandas INSIDE a greenplum database, and if so how?
I am inside greenplum. I am creating a function with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction() RETURNS
text AS $$ 
...
python code
...
rv = plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
...

$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
SELECT public.myfunction()
```

The command `rv = plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")` generates an object of type PlyResult. At this point, I want to analyze the data in rv with python pandas, for instance. How can I convert rv to a dataframe?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Here is one of my examples:

```
drop function if exists describe_yelp();
create or replace function describe_yelp(
OUT stats text,
OUT stars numeric,
OUT cool numeric,
OUT useful numeric,
OUT funny numeric,
OUT txt_length numeric)
returns setof record
as $$
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
yelp=pd.DataFrame.from_records(plpy.execute('select * from yelp'))[['stars','cool','useful','funny','text']]
yelp['txt_length'] = yelp['text'].apply(len)
return yelp.describe().to_records()      
$$
language plpythonu;
```

There are more examples of Greenplum - Pandas - Numpy - etc. integration in my blog:
https://dwhsys.com/2018/05/06/data-mining-in-mpp-database/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `pd.DataFrame(rv[0:])`.
Below is a test in Postgres

```
postgres=# do $$
postgres$# import numpy as np
postgres$# import pandas as pd
postgres$# 
postgres$# iris = plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM iris LIMIT 3")
postgres$# plpy.notice(type(iris[0:]))
postgres$# iris = pd.DataFrame(iris[0:])
postgres$# 
postgres$# X = iris[['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']].values
postgres$# plpy.notice(type(X))
postgres$# plpy.notice(X)
postgres$# 
postgres$# $$ language plpython3u;
NOTICE:  <class 'list'>
NOTICE:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
NOTICE:  [[Decimal('5.10') Decimal('3.50') Decimal('1.40') Decimal('0.20')]
 [Decimal('4.90') Decimal('3.00') Decimal('1.40') Decimal('0.20')]
 [Decimal('4.70') Decimal('3.20') Decimal('1.30') Decimal('0.20')]]
DO
postgres=#
```